# Misplaced noalign when using >{\centering}

Tags: tables, exam

I have the below code, and I want to center the col. elemnts so I used {||>{\centering}p{0.5\textwidth}||>{\centering}>p{0.3\textwidth}|}, but I got this error "\misplaced noalign" for the \hline command .. any idea how to fix the problem?.

```
\begin{table}[h]
        \label{1}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{0.5\textwidth}|>p{0.3\textwidth}|}
            \hline
            \rowcolor{Gainsboro!60}
            Student Name &Student ID \myhash \\
            \hline
            & \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Replace `\centering` with `\centering\arraybackslash` and add the `array` package.

Comment: it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to horizontally center the contents of a `p` type column, use `\centering\arraybackslash` instead of just `\centering`. Additionally, and in order to use the `>{...}` syntax, you will also have to load the `array` package.

Thus, the following example should give you the desired result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
        \label{1}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{0.5\textwidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.3\textwidth}|}
            \hline
            \rowcolor{Gainsboro!60}
            Student Name &Student ID  \\
            \hline
            & \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Since I assume student ames and their IDs are short enough to not require linebreaks within the corresponding table cells, you could also go for the `w` type columns that are available when loading the `array` package instead.

```
\begin{tabular}{|wl{0.5\textwidth}|wc{0.3\textwidth}|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{Gainsboro!60}
    Student Name &Student ID  \\
    \hline
    & \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

If you want your table to automaticaly adapt to the width of the widest contents without adding additional wite space, you can use a simple

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
```

instead.

A remark on the `\label` and the use of `table`:  `\label` only really makes sense in combination with a corresponding `\caption` and if you later on want to reference the table. (e.g. as in "For an overview see table 1"). The `table` environment only makes sense if you want your table to float. If you don't want this behaviour, don't use `table`.